# error C2065: 'nowhere' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So, I'm trying to make a text based game in C++ Using Visual Studio 2010. Here are some of the code blocks that I think are related. If you need anymore, don't hesitate to ask me.

I'm trying to create a class for a game called places. I make a place, and it has another "place" to the North, South, East, and West of it. I'm just really confused right now. I'm a noob at this stuff. I may just be looking over something.

```
//places.h------------------------
#include "place.h"

//Nowhere place
string nowheredescr = "A strange hole to nowhere";
place nowhere(&nowheredescr, &nowhere, &nowhere, &nowhere, &nowhere); //Error occurs here
//

//place.h------------------------
#ifndef place_h
#define place_h

#include "classes.h"

class place
{
public:
    place(string *Sdescription, place *Snorth, place *Ssouth, place *Swest, place *Seast);
    ~place(void);
private:
    string *description;
    place *north;
    place *south;
    place *east;
    place *west;
};

#endif

//place.cpp-------------------
#include "place.h"
#include <iostream>


place::place(string *Sdescription, place *Snorth, place *Ssouth, place *Swest, place *Seast)
{
    description = Sdescription;
    north = Snorth;
    south = Ssouth;
    west = Swest;
    east = Seast;
}


place::~place(void)
{
}
```

Comment: updated with @dasblinkenlight 's suggestion.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm getting this 4 times: "1>c:\users\jackson\google drive\public\c++ projects\parabellum\parabellum\places.cpp(5): error C2065: 'nowhere' : undeclared identifier"

And for some reason your answer got deleted :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following syntax would solve the error

```
place nowhere = place(&nowheredescr, &nowhere, &nowhere, &nowhere, &nowhere);
```

That is explained in C++03 standard, 3.3.1/1

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator (clause 8) and before its initializer (if any)

In OP example, `place nowhere(.....)` represents a declarator, therefore `nowhere` used as a constructor parameter is considered undeclared.
In my example, the `place nowhere` is a declarator and `place(.....)` is an initializer, therefore `nowhere` becomes declared at that point.